# как получить external storage на Android 2.3?

Tags: java, android, файлы

Разрабатываю приложение, которое должно иметь доступ к файловой системе. На android 4+ все хорошо, но на 2.3 и ниже я получаю пустой список файлов.

```
private FilesFactory() {
        ArrayList<MyFile> mFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();      
        File[] files = getFilesArray(dir.getPath());
        if (files != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                mFiles.add(i, new MyFile(files[i]));
            }
    }
```

Код AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.myapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>

    <activity
        android:name=".FilesActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="file/*" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission не нужен если есть `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, это даже у него в описании написано, но к вопросу это никак не относится.

Я еще на 2.1 использовал такой код для записи и он отлично работал:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/files";
File f = new File(path);
f.mkdirs();
```

Вы же по всей видимости хотите получить список файлов в корне карты памяти? Попробуйте вместо `dir.getPath()` использовать `dir.getAbsolutePath()`